# "hava" tag should probably be renamed to "java"

Tags: support, tags

Today I saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743512/internal-working-of-concurrenthashmap) tagged "hava" and the question was obviously about "java", I fixed the question tag but how can the ["hava" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hava/info) be deleted? I think it's a typo and it's useless (0 question tagged with it).

Comment: Once the `hava` tag is no longer being used by any question it will automatically be culled from existence. No further action is required.

Comment: @slugster ok, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: hrmph; if you did that 20 seconds earlier it would have saved me a lot of time finding that dupe myself :)

Comment: @Wooble lol! First step is looking for a matching [meta-tag:faq] entry, so in this case [tags faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags+faq) - then it's easy to find the relevant post. :)